# Is there a way to cycle through workspaces?

Tags: workspaces

I might be missing it, but I only saw a way to move one workspace to the left, right, up and down. Is there a keybind to cycle through them all continuously?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ArrowKey</kbd> works.

You can also do:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> gives you a overview, and then you can double click the workspace you want.

Comment: I saw those. I disabled two workspaces with Ubuntu Tweaks and was hoping to just cycle through the two with ctrl+space. While those methods work, I was hoping to just get it down to one keybind for a complete swap between the two I have.